# Как узнать о существовании в Soap-ответе xml тега?

Tags: delphi, soap

Soap-сервер возвращает ответ иногда с xml-тегом 'DELIVERY_DATE', а иногда без него. Как написать if-условие, чтобы различать их, только **без создания xml-документа**, прямо из возвращаемого soap-ответа?

Я пробовал так:

```
for i := 0 to FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
begin
            strCreate_Date:=FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['CREATE_DATE'];

//if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].NodeName='DELIVERY_DATE') then ...            
if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE')<>Nil) then
strDelivery_Date:=FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE'];
else ;

CDSGetBuyerWaybills.Append;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('create_date').AsString:=strCreate_Date;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('delivery_date').AsString:=strDelivery_Date;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('activate_date').AsString:=strActivate_Date;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.Post;
end;
```

но он **никогда** не находит тега  и переходит на else, в цикле игнорируются оба оператора- если напишу так:

```
if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE')<>Nil) then...
```

или так:

```
if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].NodeName='DELIVERY_DATE') then ...
```

а в xml-е тег 'DELIVERY_DATE' точно есть.

Soap-ответ имеет вид:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<WAYBILL_LIST xmlns="">
    <WAYBILL>
         <ID>206405566</ID>
         <TYPE>2</TYPE>
         <CREATE_DATE>2015-09-29T12:10:53</CREATE_DATE>
         <TRANSPORT_COAST>0</TRANSPORT_COAST>
         <DELIVERY_DATE>2015-10-03T10:34:43</DELIVERY_DATE>
         <STATUS>2</STATUS>
         <ACTIVATE_DATE>2015-09-29T12:10:55</ACTIVATE_DATE>
         <FULL_AMOUNT>279.99</FULL_AMOUNT>
         <CAR_NUMBER>UJU991</CAR_NUMBER>
         <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0198315109</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
         <CLOSE_DATE>2015-10-03T10:34:43</CLOSE_DATE>
         <S_USER_ID>26461</S_USER_ID>
         <BEGIN_DATE>2015-09-29T12:10:53</BEGIN_DATE>
   </WAYBILL>
   <WAYBILL>
         <ID>207247983</ID>
         <TYPE>2</TYPE>
         <CREATE_DATE>2015-10-03T12:20:09</CREATE_DATE>
         <TRANSPORT_COAST>0</TRANSPORT_COAST>
         <STATUS>1</STATUS>
         <ACTIVATE_DATE>2015-10-03T12:20:11</ACTIVATE_DATE>
         <FULL_AMOUNT>279.56</FULL_AMOUNT>
         <CAR_NUMBER>YPY088</CAR_NUMBER>
         <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0199129044</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
         <S_USER_ID>26461</S_USER_ID>
         <BEGIN_DATE>2015-10-03T12:20:09</BEGIN_DATE>
    </WAYBILL>
</WAYBILL_LIST>
```

Comment: Что значит "без создания xml-документа", если он у вас уже есть? Вы же обращаетесь к XMLNode.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  я нигде не создаю xml-документа, Soap-response сам содержит готовый xml-документ(кроме header-а), откуда я и читаю.

Comment: Вот и работайте с уже имеющимся xml-документом. Не нужно работать со строкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее всего проверить уже полученный XML на предмет тэга

```
If Pos('<DELIVERY_DATE>', XmlResponse) > 0 then // значит тэг есть.
...
else // тэга нет.
```

P.S. Увидел условие **без создания XML-документа**. Встречный вопрос; а почему? Зачем усложнять? Зачем ковыряться в SOAP-конверте и нагромождать лишние строки кода?

На каждую задачу есть изящное решение. И на эту тоже. Изящество здесь будет в том, чтобы найти тэг *уже в ответе*. При этом сам XML-файл можно не торопиться записывать на диск, а операции поиска тэга провести в памяти.

**UPDATE**
Думаю, проблема может быть в переменной, которая объявлена как `var`. В этом случае, я бы советовал объявить промежуточную переменную `var s: string` и присвоить ей значение `XMLNode.Xml`. Таким образом, текст XML попросту скопируется в переменную `s` и с ним можно будет производить дальнейшие манипуляции.

**UPDATE 2**
Как выяснилось в чате, нужно *корректно* проверить наличие элемента `<DELIVERY_DATE>`, не вызвав при этом исключений и не прибегая к прямому парсингу строк, что конкретно в данной ситуации будет неразумно. Таким образом, предложенные выше методики - попытки дать ответ на *некорректно сформулированный вопрос*.

Для того, чтобы корректно проверить наличие элемента через MSXMLDOM, нужно использовать метод `FindNode()` который доступен для коллекции `IXMLNodeList`. В коде это будет выглядеть вот так (для наглядности я использовал `with..do`):

```
with FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i] do
    //сначала обязательно проверим наличие элемента
    //чтобы потом не попытаться обратиться к неициализированному объекту и не вызвать AV
    if ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE') = nil then //элемента не существует
        ShowMessage('There is no DELIVERY_DATE element in this Waybill!')
    else //элемент существует
    begin
      ...
    end;
```

Если посмотреть на иерархю вложенности объектов, то все выглядит очень логично:

- `XMLNode` в коде выше означает всю коллекцию Waybills (то есть `<WAYBILL_LIST>`)
- Далее мы пробегаем в цикле через все дочерние ноды `WAYBILL`, "заглядываем" в них и ищем в их дочерних нодах (`ChildNodes`) нужные нам элементы
- Поиск нужного элемента делаем через `FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE')`. Если элемент не найден, то значение будет равно `nil`.

Дальше все очень легко.

И на дессерт: **ПОЧЕМУ НЕ РАБОТАЛ POS()**
Потому что всякие штуки типа `ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE']` возвращают не `string`, а `System.OleVariant` который не может быть implicitly-преобразован в строку. По этой причине выбрасывалось исключение.

**UPDATE 3**
Вот скрин полностью работающего кода. Который отрабатывает "ненахождение" тэга и выдаёт это в лог внизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 4**
Вот код, который не просто отвечает на вопрос, а еще и решает конкретную задачу автора-программиста. Которую должен решать он сам, а не мы.

```
//показываем что вне зависимости от наличия/отсутствия тэга
//мы будем добавлять записи в DataGrid
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.Append;

if FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE') = nil then
begin
    //логируем информацию о том, что WB без DELIVERY_DATE
    Memo.Lines.Add ('There is no DELIVERY_DATE node in this WB with ID=' + IntToStr(i));
    //произвольно устанавливаем значение переменной strDelivery_Date
    strDelivery_Date := 'active';
end
else //иначе!!! (если тэг есть)
begin
    strDelivery_Date:=FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE'];
    strYear:=copy(strDelivery_Date,1,4); //за такое преобразование даты
    strMonth:=copy(strDelivery_Date,6,2); //нужно нещадно бить розгами!
    strDay:=copy(strDelivery_Date,9,2);

    strDelivery_Date:=strDay+FormatSettings.DateSeparator+strMonth+FormatSettings.DateSeparator+strYear;
end;

//теперь, когда все условия проверены и параметры установлены
//начинаем запиливать значения в DataGrid:

CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('ID').AsString := FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['WAYBILL_NUMBER'];
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('amount').AsString :=VarToStrDef(FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['FULL_AMOUNT'], '');
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('seller').AsString := VarToStrDef(FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['SELLER_NAME'], '');
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('create_date').AsString:=strCreate_Date;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('delivery_date').AsString:=strDelivery_Date;
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('activate_date').AsString:=strActivate_Date;

//в самом конце проверяем статус
if FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['STATUS']=1 then
    CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('status').AsString:='active'
    else
    CDSGetBuyerWaybills.FieldByName('status').AsString:='ended';

//и наконец постим все это в базу
CDSGetBuyerWaybills.Post;
```

Comment: Interface Unknown, попробовал так: 1) If Pos('<DELIVERY_DATE>', FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.Text) > 0 then .... выводит: "Element Waybill-list doesn't contain a single text node"  2)  If Pos('<DELIVERY_DATE>', FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult) > 0 then... выводит: "there is no overloaded version of 'pos' that can be called with these arguments "

Comment: `FromServ` - это что у нас? Компонент?

Comment: ToServ, FromServ-переменные процедурного типа.
var WBS:WayBillsSoap;                                        ToServ:get_buyer_waybills;
FromServ:get_buyer_waybillsResponse;  
........
WBS := GetWayBillsSoap(false,'',Fmain.HTTPRIO1);
ToServ:=get_buyer_waybills.Create;FromServ:=WBS.get_buyer_waybills(ToServ);

Comment: в FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult я получаю чистый XML ответ и свободно манипулирую с ним. например:
Memo.Text := FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.Xml; или 
strDelivery_Date:=FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE'];  т.е. могу из него получить любой тег, но не могу написат оператор как узнать отсутствие тега!

Comment: Не нужно писать код в комментариях. Лучше отредактируйте вопрос и туда добавьте этот код. А так же что возвращают эти функции.

Comment: Оператор If (Pos(FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE'], FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.ToString) > 0) then.... пропускает тот часит цикла, в который должен исполнятся тогда, когда тег существует. Может быть потому, что childnode не <DELIVERY_DATE>, а  <WAYBILL>? А <DELIVERY_DATE> это "childchildnode", т.е. 2-го порядка?!

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Не получается потому, что в xml-е  всегда находится хоть один <Waybill> тег, который содержит тег <DELIVERY_DATE>  и поэтому в стринге всегда будет.
В посте добавил проект(3,5мб).

Comment: Тогда надо посчитать количество WB и потом определить (тоже посчитать) количество WB с тэгом DELIVERY_DATE. Если значения будут разниться, то значит есть как минимум один WB без DELIVERY_DATE. Фактически, это то же самое, если бы мы просматривали каждую ноду `<WAYBILL>` на предмет тэга.

Comment: Interface Unknown, дело сложнее,  если значения будут разниться, не значит что точно  DELIVERY_DATE не хватает, потому что другие теги тоже могут остутствовать, например <CLOSE_DATE>.
Как я понял, нужен  один for-цикл для Waybill-ов, и внутри второй цикл для дочерых и тогда во внутреннем цикле понадобится предложенный вами string. А как перебирать во внешнем цикле <Waybyll> ноды ? for i := 0 to FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode....... - 1 ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29844/discussion-between-interface-unknown-and-davidkoko).

Comment: Будет проще, если вы отредактируете вопрос и добавите туда структуру XML-ответа. Критические данные можно удалить. Тогда мы просто посоветуем как этот XML нужно правильно распарсить и какими парсерами.

Comment: Interface Unknown, ничего нового в вашем коде-дополнении не вижу. if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE')<‌​>Nil) в коде итак есть, но всегда возвращает Nil- т.е.не находит <DELIVERY_DATE>.

Comment: @davidkoko дружище, нужно ценить труд других людей. Я полностью разобрался в том бардаке, который ты называешь кодом и исчерпывающе ответил тебе на вопрос.

Comment: Interface Unknown, пришлите тогда назад измененный проект! 
Вы запустили программу и в поле delivery_date получили значения?  Неужели не выдите, что в ващем коде не слова нового!  if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('delivery_date')<‌​>Nil) в коде итак есть, но всегда возвращает Nil- не находит delivery_date!  Я написал моё решение и загрузил снимок DbGrid-а! Так трудно 3,5мб zip обратно переслать?

Comment: @davidkoko, вы, похоже, чего-то не понимаете... На Stackoverflow **ничего не делают за вас**. И не "пересылают вам обратно" "измененные проекты". Тут сообщество профессиональных программистов, которые помогают друг другу найти ответы на конкретные вопросы. Я указал в чем проблема. У меня ваш код работает. Если вы не понимаете ничего в собственном коде и не можете самостоятельно дополнить его правильным решением, то тогда это, увы, не сюда...

Comment: У меня отлавливает отсутствие тэга при i = 3 и выдает оповещение. При этом никаких исключений не происходит. Програма продолжает работать в штатном режиме.

Comment: Не работает правильно у вас в коде оператор if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE')=Nil)  и поэтому не показываете не полную for цикл и не проект. А у меня работает, а как работает я уже показал выше!

Comment: О чем речь вообще?! Я не пишу ваш код и не думал что-то куда присылать обратно. Я показал вам как правильно найти элемент `DELIVERY_DATE` в XML-документе! Иными словами - **я ответил на вопрос**. А вы дали свой "ответ" целиком основываясь на моём.

Answer (score -1):

Сам решил вопрос по-другому:

```
 if (FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE']<>Null)
    then 
    strDelivery_Date:=FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildValues['DELIVERY_DATE']
    else;
```

код правильно работает(на рисунке один deliver_date пустой), хотя условие другое(if...<>Null).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А что касается кода, который предлагал Interface Unknown:

```
 if FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].childnodes.FindNode('DELIVERY_DATE') = nil then //элемента не существует
            ShowMessage('There is no DELIVERY_DATE element in this Waybill!')
        else //элемент существует
        begin
          ...
        end;
```

тоже правильно работает! Спасибо ему!

Comment: Я в шоке. Я дал правильный ответ на вопрос, который ты _в точности скопировал_ в своем "ответе"...))) И "ничего нового не увидел", говоришь?

Comment: Может просто нужна срочная операция по пересадке рук обратно в плечи? У меня все работает :-) Скрин вверу, а нормально и правильно форматированный код в моей XE4 :-)

Comment: Я не предлагал такого кода. Вы, видимо, чего-то не досмотрели. Я использовал инструкцию `with FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i] do` где `ChildNodes[i]` - это и есть все Waybills!